# Creating Dynamic Variables & Function in JS

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, this

I'm fairly new to JS but am familiar with AS2(Flash). In Flash I can put variables inside movieclips (objects) and have attempted to do something similar here with dropdowns:

http://tamalecreative.com.au/korban/scripts/dropdown.js

specifically:

```
   function dropOpen() {
       dropClose(this)
       this.overTrue = true;
       console.log(this.overTrue);
       myNum = 0;
       this.liLength = ($(this).find('ul').children().length)+1;
       for (i=0;i<=this.liLength;i++) {
           this.animateTimer = window.setTimeout(animateIn, (80 * i), this);
       }
   };
```

My problem is with the 'this.overTrue' boolean variable. It seems to work in everything but IE. I get the error that the object 'overTrue' doesn't exist. Which kind of makes sense to me since I never declared it. Is there a way for me to declare the var 'overTrue' inside 'this'? Or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in which version of IE are you experiencing this?

Comment: All versions. The error I get is: "Unable to get value of the property 'overTrue': object is null or undefined"

Comment: for reference: http://tamalecreative.com.au/korban/product.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like IE is screwing up with the last parameter, a possible workaround might be:

```
var that = this;
this.animateTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
  animateIn(that);
}, (80 * i));
```

In every 'sane' browser, `setTimeout` signature is like this:

```
window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

In IE *however* the signature is [slightly different](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
window.setTimeout(vCode, iMilliSeconds [, sLanguage])
```

Bravo IE. You've surprised me one more time

Comment: You're a champ Pablo. Works perfectly now. Magic!